# mouse selected text, text that is deleted

Tags: mouse

I use Ubuntu 14.04

In any windows which you can write and edit text, when you left-click the mouse and hold it， don't let it go， then move the mouse to select some text or word, with your mouse moving the word that selected auto deleted!

so, the problem is , when i want to left-click to select some word or text to copy or cut, i can't do that because the text that i want to copy or cut delete when i select to them？

is there anyone else meet this problem? and can anyone help me ?
i really don't know how could this happen

By the way, sometime this can be usefull, but the problem is i can't copt and past the part that i want！

Answer (score 3):

Found out that the bug is with "ibus" input.

Didn't find a way to fix it. So in the end I switch to fcitx and that fixed my problem.

Comment: My bad, kinda new here. I have changed my reply to be an answer now, XD